# How to select lang output in HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm developing WP site and I'm using Gtranslate for auto translating all content in the website. But I want to change some strings manually when language switches.

I assume that first I need to target lang given value in HTML with if statement and only then lauch :

```
<script>
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Home/g, 'Main Page');
</script>'
```

What script should I write [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSdBB.jpg) to target this part of the code?

Comment: Hi, there really is not enough info above for people to be able to assist you. I suggest you look at places like youtube to get an understanding of Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to review the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what sort of question you can ask here and the best way to ask it so you get the help you need

Answer (score 0):

Document.documentElement returns the Element that is the root element of the document (for example, the  element for HTML documents).

```js
document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'tr')
```

Ref: [Developer.Mozilla Document.documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? I need to lauch replace text part code only when button russian language is pressed.

Comment: I did not understand what you wanted to do, you can edit the place you showed in the picture with the code it gave you.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.